# MiniMagic resize

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, minimagick, mogrify

im using MiniMagick to resize some images on my server. I am having issues forcing dimensions on it. The MiniMagick git documentation states that it uses the [mogrify](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php) commands.  Looking into it further, There are sever commands you can use in your resize such as:

`-resize "230x200>"`
`-resize "230x200<"`
`-resize "230x200!"`

I am looking to use the `!` but it seems like it is not working.

```
     img = sftp.download!("local_promos/#{@image_name}")  
     ri = MiniMagick::Image.read(img)
     ri.resize "230x200!" # ! get ignored and it does not resize
     ri.write('#{img_dir}#{@image_name}')
```

i ran mogrify command in the command like and it worked fine. What seems to be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was the gem mini_magic. I was using  -v 3.5.0. it was escaping string using `Shellwords.escape(value.to_s)` The newer version 3.6.0 fixed my issue.